# What's the difference between TYPE and DEVICETYPE directives in ifcfg scripts?

Tags: networking, centos, rhel, init-script

While learning the Network Teaming objective of the RHCE (RHEL7) exam I noticed that examples use `DEVICETYPE` directive in the ifcfg scripts for master and port interfaces. I knew there was `TYPE` directive that I've seen in other ifcfg scripts before. The question arisen was what's the difference between those two directives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After checking man pages, initscripts (package owning ifcfg scripts) documentation in /usr/share/doc/initscripts-*/sysconfig.txt, initscripts mailing list, and several bugs from redhat's bug tracker the only thing I understood is that to avoid problems those two directives should not be used in the same ifcfg script.

I then forwarded my question to Jiri Pirko, Network Teaming (libteam) project maintainer. Here is the reply I got from him:

> Well the reason [for using DEVICETYPE] was political, not technical. Using DEVICETYPE, you can simply install additional initscripts with the package (teamd). But that does not matter anymore because initscripts now directly support team, so you can use TYPE.

---

Contrary to Jiri's answer I must note that according to my tests it still matters what directive is used on my system. Network teaming interface works with `DEVICETYPE=Team` directive, but doesn't work with `TYPE=Team` directive.

My configuration:

- CentOS Linux release 7.0.1406
- libteam-1.9-15.el7.x86_64
- teamd-1.9-15.el7.x86_64
- initscripts-9.49.17-1.el7.x86_64

---

An update from Jiri after I pointed that usage of DEVICETYPE over TYPE still matters for teaming interfaces:

> The support is added by following commit:
>   https://git.fedorahosted.org/cgit/initscripts.git/commit/?id=3235be4a3da91bc91c698b318935240dbdf81aac
>
> If it is not in 7.0, I believe it will be in 7.1